# Click event listener working but not keydown?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does this work:

```
buttonGrid.addEventListener('click', e => {
  calculate(e);
});

let calculate = (e) => {
if (e.target.id === "back") {
displayArea.textContent = displayArea.textContent.substring(0, 
   displayArea.textContent.length - 1);
}
}
```

But not this...

```
buttonGrid.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  calculate(e);
});

let calculate = (e) => {
if (e.keyCode === 8) {
displayArea.textContent = displayArea.textContent.substring(0, 
   displayArea.textContent.length - 1);
}
}
```

See lines 30-45 at: https://jsfiddle.net/s9ebLdvt/2/

If I log out the typeof e.keyCode I get number. Hence I use a number rather than a string.

I've also tried switching the === to == but get the same issue.

Weirdly if I place a console log in the if statement it fires it just doesn't compute the code?

Comment: It does work, but you are not preventing other code from execution afterwards. Try adding a `return` at the end of the the if-statement.